# Flutter, run all tests in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I need to be able to run all tests at once in my flutter project.

I can run each individual test function or all tests in a single .dart file but when I attempt to run all tests in the project I get a cache error:

> Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in
> "C:\Users\Vahid\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org_fe_analyzer_shared-26.0.0".

That path is not where I installed flutter. I have flutter in `C:\fluttersdk` which is also the path that I provided to android studio when creating this project.

That file that Android Studio cannot locate, is actually there in the right path `C:\fluttersdk\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\_fe_analyzer_shared-26.0.0`.

How should I set Android Studio to look for that file in the correct path?

I tried adding a PUB_CACHE environment variable and appending it to PATH with no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a new configuration

[image: Add a new configuration]

2. Select all tests in a directory

[image: Select all tests in a directory]

3. Run all your tests as you would run your app
   You can just run your tests(1) or run them with coverage(2)

[image: Run tests]

Comment: Didn't work for me. Tried adding new configuration both as "dart test" and "flutter test". Setting the directory to `/test` in my project folder. It says `No tests were found`.

Comment: Actually I'm no longer getting that cache error. All I get now is the `No tests were found` error.

Comment: Your dart files inside the test folder should all end with `_test.dart`, its a convention. If they do not finish like that they are not recognized. Eg: `home_test.dart`